# Wicket-Atmosphere configuration error

Tags: wicket, atmosphere, wicket-6, wicket-1.6, atmosphere.js

I am new to Atmosphere, I have created a wicket quick start application(6.19.0) and configured Atmosphere but getting following error:

```
2016-11-09 17:29:31 WARN  AtmosphereFramework:1679 - Failed using comet support: org.atmosphere.container.Tomcat7CometSupport, error: Tomcat failed to detect this is a Comet application because context.xml is missing or the Http11NioProtocol Connector is not enabled.You must use the atmosphere-native-runtime dependency in order to use native Comet Support
If that's not the case, you can also remove META-INF/context.xml and WEB-INF/lib/atmosphere-compat-tomcat7.jar Is the NIO or APR Connector enabled?
2016-11-09 17:29:31 ERROR AtmosphereFramework:1682 - If you have more than one Connector enabled, make sure they both use the same protocol, e.g NIO/APR or HTTP for all. If not, org.atmosphere.container.BlockingIOCometSupport will be used and cannot be changed.
2016-11-09 17:29:31 WARN  AtmosphereFramework:1694 - Using org.atmosphere.container.BlockingIOCometSupport
2016-11-09 17:29:31 WARN  Component:3969 - Markup id set on a component that is usually not rendered into markup. Markup id: version4, component id: version, component tag: container.
```

pom.xml as follows:

```
<properties>
    <wicket.version>6.19.0</wicket.version>
    <jetty.version>7.6.13.v20130916</jetty.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <wtp.version>none</wtp.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.wicket</groupId>
        <artifactId>wicket-core</artifactId>
        <version>${wicket.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.atmosphere</groupId>
        <artifactId>atmosphere-runtime</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.atmosphere</groupId>
        <artifactId>atmosphere-runtime-native</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.atmosphere</groupId>
                <artifactId>atmosphere-compat-tomcat7</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.wicket</groupId>
        <artifactId>wicket-atmosphere</artifactId>
        <version>0.18</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.16</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.11</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate</groupId>
        <artifactId>jetty-all-server</artifactId>
        <version>${jetty.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

web.xml:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>AtmosphereServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>applicationClassName</param-name>
        <param-value>com.cg.web.test.WicketApplication</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>org.atmosphere.useWebSocket</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>org.atmosphere.useNative</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>filterMappingUrlPattern</param-name>
        <param-value>/*</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>0</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

[image: List of jar files in WEB-INF/lib]

And there is no context.xml file. I have removed the comment from following line in server.xml

```
<Connector port="9443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
           maxThreads="150" SSLEnabled="true" scheme="https" secure="true"
           keystorefile="file:///D:/SSL/keystore" keystorepass="changeit"
           clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" />
```

Can anyone provide some idea on this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'd recommend you to upgrade to a newer version of Wicket. This will bring a newer version of Atmosphere as well. And the issue might be gone...

Comment: @martin-g currently I am forced to implement this in existing wicket project which runs on 6.19.0. So is there anything that we can do with this?

Comment: You can try to upgrade only Atmosphere.